# Arithmetic inside vue js expressions

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have some html code and i am displaying some value like this

```
 <h4 class="text-dark pull-right">
        <strong>USD {{item.addbedrooms[0].the_price_per_night }}</strong>
 </h4>
```

I got the displayed value from a web service that only allows one to display the data like above. Is there a way i can do some arithmetic on the expression like

```
<strong>USD {{item.addbedrooms[0].the_price_per_night }} x {{duration}} </strong>
```

This produces `USD 27*1` and not a multiplication. Is it possible to multiple at this level?

Comment: `<strong>USD {{item.addbedrooms[0].the_price_per_night x duration}} </strong>`
Isn't this working?

Comment: @scar-2018 No its not. Its an error even.

Comment: This worked though <strong>USD {{item.addbedrooms[0].the_price_per_night * duration}}</strong> it should have been an asterick

Comment: Yeah, Arithmetic operations should be working in {{}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything you output from `{{ }}` is converted to a string in the template. You can do it by having the arithmetic operation within the `{{ }}`

```html
<strong>USD {{item.addbedrooms[0].the_price_per_night * duration}} </strong>
```

But I would recommend that you optimize your array via a `computed` and not add any methods into your template.